# Sample a zone in texture painting

Tags: texturing

Is it possibile in Blender to sample an entire zone of a mesh texture to replicate it with painting?
For example, I have an arm like this, I want to sample the pattern of the arm to paint all the arm with this color.

[image]

If I use the shortcut S to sample a color, the result is this:
[image]

Obviously there is a difference between the color of the arm and the sampled color, how can I sample an entire zone of color instead a single color to paint my arm?
Thanks to everybody

Comment: Hello, have you tried the Clone brush? It works in the 3D view. It also works in the Image Editor but I don't know how... It also depends on what you call "sample an entire zone of a mesh texture", Clone samples another part of the image texture

Comment: so please give a bit more details

Comment: Clone brush is exactly what I wanted, thank you so much!